# MySQL trigger update error 1111

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, linux, php, ubuntu

Trying to update the "size" column with the value of "file" column.

```
BEGIN
  set NEW.size=SUM(LENGTH(file));
END
```

---

Executing:

```
UPDATE `table`.`library` SET `_by`='Danis555, Vovan244' WHERE `id`='20';
```

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
>
> ERROR 1111: 1111: Invalid use of group function
>   SQL Statement:
>   UPDATE `table`.`library` SET `_by`='Danis555, Vovan244' WHERE `id`='20'

Comment: What's the reasoning behind `SUM(LENGTH())`?

Comment: To get the size of of my blob column(file).

Comment: How many `LENGTH`s do you expect to be returned for one column in one row that you need to `SUM` them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET NEW.size = LENGTH(OLD.file);
```

No `SUM`, since there is only one row.
Specify which `file` with `OLD.`.